# User Profile Property: Initials

Tags: 2010, user-profile-property

I'm looking for a property in the User Profile Properties where the Initials are stored. Is there a default one? If not, I know how to create a new one, so I don't need any code. I'm just looking for the property but cannot find any (I guess there should be one?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No anwser here so I guess there isn't one. So I created the property myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the default properties:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh147513.aspx

Here is how you can create a view of all the properties and their values for each user:
http://iedaddy.com/2012/03/sharepoint-2010sql-view-to-get-user-profile-property-bag-values/